# Eclipse builder: How does it work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know any details on the underlying eclipse builder that sends jobs to the compiler and get its report? and how to tap to it? The level of abstraction that the builder extension offers is too high and the information insufficient. So I implemented an IResourceChangeListener and played with the ResourceDelta in order to get the messages from an IMarker. It works perfectly, however I realized the message is just returning a string. So my question is, how do I do in order to get the type/reference of the object where the error is, what type of error, what class it should belongs to and all available info.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question?  What extra information do you need over what is part of the builder API?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [the builder documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm)?

And there is also [This article by John](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html).

I think between those two and looking at the code you will find everything you need to know.

Comment: Yes, I already looked at those articles and unfortunately they are not that great of a help. Thanks

Comment: Once you have the `IResource`, you have to turn to JDT.  See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_compile.htm for a discussion about java compile problem `IMarker`s and the rest of the JDT Plug-in Developer Guide for how to turn an IResource into the Java Model AST.